# How to split the dataset for cross validation, learning curve, and final evaluation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, python, scikit-learn

**What is an appropriate strategy for splitting the dataset?**

*I ask for feedback on the following approach* (not on the individual parameters like `test_size` or `n_iter`, but if I used `X`, `y`, `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, and `y_test` appropriately and if the sequence makes sense):

(extending [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html) example from the scikit-learn documentation)

#### 1. Load the dataset

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target
```

#### 2. Split into training and test set (e.g., 80/20)

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

#### 3. Choose estimator

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
estimator = SVC(kernel='linear')
```

#### 4. Choose cross-validation iterator

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
cv = ShuffleSplit(X_train.shape[0], n_iter=10, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

#### 5. Tune the hyperparameters

applying the cross-validation iterator on the **training set**

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np
gammas = np.logspace(-6, -1, 10)
classifier = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, cv=cv, param_grid=dict(gamma=gammas))
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

#### 6. Debug algorithm with learning curve

`X_train` is randomly split into a training and a test set 10 times (`n_iter=10`). Each point on the training-score curve is the average of 10 scores where the model was trained and evaluated on the first *i* training examples. Each point on the cross-validation score curve is the average of 10 scores where the model was trained on the first *i* training examples and evaluated on all examples of the test set.

```
from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve
title = 'Learning Curves (SVM, linear kernel, $\gamma=%.6f$)' %classifier.best_estimator_.gamma
estimator = SVC(kernel='linear', gamma=classifier.best_estimator_.gamma)
plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X_train, y_train, cv=cv)
plt.show()
```

[image: Learning curve]

[plot_learning_curve()](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/plot_learning_curve.html) can be found in the current dev version of scikit-learn (0.15-git).

#### 7. Final evaluation on the test set

```
classifier.score(X_test, y_test)
```

#### 7a. Test over-fitting in model selection with nested cross-validation (using the whole dataset)

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(classifier, X, y)
```

**Additional question:** *Does it make sense to replace step 7 by nested cross-validation? Or should nested cv be seen as complementary to step 7*

(the code seems to work with k-fold cross validation in scikit-learn, but not with shuffle & split. So `cv` needs to be changed above to make the code work)

#### 8. Train final model on whole dataset

```
classifier.fit(X, y)
```

EDIT: I now agree with cbeleites that step 7a doesn't make much sense in this sequence. So I wouldn't adopt that.

Comment: Which accuracy scoring rule are you using?  If it is classification accuracy, such an improper scoring rule will undo much of the work you've gone to.

Comment: I used the default which is indeed classification accuracy. I know that, e.g., F1 would be more appropriate. But here I'm just interested if the splits are used OK.

Comment: The accuracy measure makes such a huge impact that other choices may not be relevant enough to spend time on.  And what is F1?

Comment: From the [scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score): "F1 score, also known as balanced F-score or F-measure. The F1 score can be interpreted as a weighted average of the precision and recall." I'm happy to change the scoring method in the above code, but I'd still be curious about the splitting.

Comment: I am almost certain that F1 is a new name for an old concept.  I think it is counterproductive to invent new names for old things.  More importantly, it is an improper scoring rule that will result in selection of the wrong features as well as adding a good deal of noise into the whole process.

Comment: ... in any case F1 shares the problems of accuracy @FrankHarrell alludes to: these  stem from counting fractions of test cases of hard classifcations. To get one of Frank's proper scoring rules, you'd need to switch to probabilistic output of the SVM, and then e.g. use Brier's score (mean squared error) instead of accuracy. I guess you could also derive a MSE-type version of F1. Such measures should indeed be better for the tuning step. For communicating the final performance, you may also need the typical ways (e.g. accuracy, F1) of expressing performance for your community.

Comment: Thanks Frank Harrell and @cbeleites. I never read that the F1-score is inappropriate for hyperparameter tuning. Then [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html#example-grid-search-digits-py) in the scikit-learn documentation using precision and recall for tuning is wrong?  Do you have a reference for correct scoring rules such as Brier's score for the tuning step?

Comment: @ta.ft: whether the approach is wrong or not depends on what you consider wrong: grid search on proportions has a serious risk of skimming variance unless you have ridiculously large numbers of independent cases. So, for many situations the claim that grid search yields the optimal model is wrong. However, if you do a proper nested validation, the outer validation gives an honest measure of the chosen "optimal" model's performance. So that is not wrong. You just don't have a guarantee that the grid search got the optimal model. As for literature, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @tobip, What is the utility of 8)? and in the 7) is the score will be calculated with the best estimator?

Comment: May I ask why a grid search over gamma is executed although you're using an SVM linear kernel?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do in step 7a. As I understand it right now, it doesn't make sense to me.

Here's how I understand your description: in step 7, you want to compare the hold-out performance with the results of a cross validation embracing steps 4 - 6. (so yes, that would be a nested setup).

The main points why I don't think this comparison makes much sense are:

- This comparison cannot detect two of the main sources of overoptimistic validation results I encounter in practice:

  - data leaks (dependence) between training and test data which is caused by a hierarchical (aka clustered) data structure, and which is not accounted for in the splitting. In my field, we have typically multiple (sometimes thousands) of readings (= rows in the data matrix) of the same patient or biological replicate of an experiment. These are not independent, so the validation splitting needs to be done at patient level. However, such a data leak occurs, you'll have it both in the splitting for the hold out set and in the cross validation splitting. Hold-out wold then be just as optimistically biased as cross validation.
  - Preprocessing of the data done on the whole data matrix, where the calculations are not independent for each row but many/all rows are used to calculation parameters for the preprocessing. Typical examples would be e.g. a PCA projection before the "actual" classification.
    Again, that would affect both your hold-out and the outer cross validation, so you cannot detect it.

  For the data I work with, both errors can easily cause the fraction of misclassifications to be underestimated by an order of magnitude!
- If you are restricted to this counted fraction of test cases type of performance, model comparisons need either extremely large numbers of test cases or ridiculously large differences in true performance. [Comparing 2 classifiers with unlimited training data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43392/comparing-2-classifiers-with-unlimited-training-data) may be a good start for further reading.

However, comparing the model quality the inner cross validation claims for the "optimal" model and the outer cross validation or hold out validation does make sense: if the discrepancy is high, it is questionable whether your grid search optimization did work (you may have skimmed variance due to the high variance of the performance measure). This comparison is easier in that you can spot trouble if you have the inner estimate being ridiculously good compared to the other - if it isn't, you don't need to worry that much about your optimization. But in any case, if your outer (7) measurement of the performance is honest and sound, you at least have a useful estimate of the obtained model, whether it is optimal or not.

IMHO measuring the learning curve is yet a different problem. I'd probably deal with that separately, and I think you need to define more clearly what you need the learning curve for (do you need the learning curve for *a* data set of the given problem, data, and classification method or the learning curve for *this* data set of the given problem, data, and classification mehtod), and a bunch of further decisions (e.g. how to deal with the model complexity as function of the training sample size? Optimize all over again, use fixed hyperparameters, decide on function to fix hyperparameters depending on training set size?)

(My data usually has so few independent cases to get the measurement of the learning curve sufficiently precise to use it in practice - but you may be better of if your 1200 rows are actually independent)

---

### update: What is "wrong" with the the scikit-learn example?

First of all, nothing is wrong with nested cross validation here. Nested validation is of utmost importance for data-driven optimization, and cross validation is a very powerful approaches (particularly if iterated/repeated).

Then, whether anything is wrong at all depends on your point of view: as long as you do an honest nested validation (keeping the outer test data strictly independent), the outer validation is a proper measure of the "optimal" model's performance. Nothing wrong with that.

But several things can and do go wrong with grid search of these proportion-type performance measures for hyperparameter tuning of SVM. Basically they mean that you may (probably?) cannont rely on the optimization. Nevertheless, as long as your outer split was done properly, even if the model is not the best possible, you have an honest estimate of the performance of the model you got.

I'll try to give intuitive explanations why the optimization may be in trouble:

- Mathematically/statisticaly speaking, the problem with the proportions is that measured proportions $\hat p$ are subject to a huge variance due to finite test sample size $n$ (depending also on the true performance of the model, $p$):
  $Var (\hat p) = \frac{p (1 - p)}{n}$

  You need ridiculously huge numbers of cases (at least compared to the numbers of cases I can usually have) in order to achieve the needed precision (bias/variance sense) for estimating recall, precision (machine learning performance sense). This of course applies also to ratios you calculate from such proportions. Have a look at the confidence intervals for binomial proportions. They are shockingly large! Often larger than the true improvement in performance over the hyperparameter grid. 
  And statistically speaking, grid search is a massive multiple comparison problem: the more points of the grid you evaluate, the higher the risk of finding some combination of hyperparameters that accidentally looks very good for the train/test split you are evaluating. This is what I mean with skimming variance. The well known optimistic bias of the inner (optimization) validation is just a symptom of this variance skimming.
- Intuitively, consider a hypothetical change of a hyperparameter, that slowly causes the model to deteriorate: one test case moves towards the decision boundary. The 'hard' proportion performance measures do not detect this until the case crosses the border and is on the wrong side. Then, however, they immediately assign a full error for an infinitely small change in the hyperparameter.
  *In order to do numerical optimization, you need the performance measure to be well behaved.* That means: neither the jumpy (not continously differentiable) part of the proportion-type performance measure nor the fact that other than that jump, actually occuring changes are not detected are suitable for the optimization.
  Proper scoring rules are defined in a way that is particularly suitable for optimization. They have their global maximum when the predicted probabilities match the true probabilities for each case to belong to the class in question.
- For SVMs you have the additional problem that not only the performance measures but also the model reacts in this jumpy fashion: small changes of the hyperparameter will not change anything. The model changes only when the hyperparameters are changes enough to cause some case to either stop being support vector or to become support vector. Again, such models are hard to optimize.

Literature:

- [Brown, L.; Cai, T. & DasGupta, A.: Interval Estimation for a Binomial Proportion, Statistical Science, 16, 101-133 (2001).](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~tcai/paper/html/Binomial-StatSci.html)
- [Cawley, G. C. & Talbot, N. L. C.: On Over-fitting in Model Selection and Subsequent Selection Bias in Performance Evaluation, Journal of Machine Learning Research, 11, 2079-2107 (2010).](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v11/cawley10a.html)
- [Gneiting, T. & Raftery, A. E.: Strictly Proper Scoring Rules, Prediction, and Estimation, Journal of the American Statistical Association, 102, 359-378 (2007). DOI: 10.1198/016214506000001437](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/016214506000001437)
- Brereton, R.: Chemometrics for pattern recognition, Wiley, (2009).
  points out the jumpy behaviour of the SVM as function of the hyperparameters.

---

### Update II: Skimming variance

what you can afford in terms of model comparison obviously depends on the number of independent cases. 
Let's make some quick and dirty simulation about the risk of skimming variance here:

`scikit.learn` says that they have 1797 are in the `digits` data.

- assume that 100 models are compared, e.g. a $10 \times 10$ grid for 2 parameters.
- assume that both parameter (ranges) do not affect the models at all,
- i.e., all models have the same true performance of, say, 97 % (typical performance for the `digits` data set).
- Run $10^4$ simulations of "testing these models" with sample size = 1797 rows in the `digits` data set

  ```
  p.true = 0.97 # hypothetical true performance for all models
  n.models = 100 # 10 x 10 grid

  n.rows = 1797 # rows in scikit digits data

  sim.test <- replicate (expr= rbinom (n= nmodels, size= n.rows, prob= p.true), 
                         n = 1e4)
  sim.test <- colMaxs (sim.test) # take best model

  hist (sim.test / n.rows, 
        breaks = (round (p.true * n.rows) : n.rows) / n.rows + 1 / 2 / n.rows, 
        col = "black", main = 'Distribution max. observed performance',
        xlab = "max. observed performance", ylab = "n runs")
  abline (v = p.outer, col = "red")
  ```

Here's the distribution for the best observed performance:

[image: skimming variance simulation]

The red line marks the true performance of all our hypothetical models. On average, we observe only 2/3 of the true error rate for the seemingly best of the 100 compared models (for the simulation we know that they all perform equally with 97% correct predictions).

This simulation is obviously very much simplified:

- In addition to the test sample size variance there is at least the variance due to model instability, so we're underestimating the variance here
- Tuning parameters affecting the model complexity will typically cover parameter sets where the models are unstable and thus have high variance.
- For the UCI digits from the example, the original data base has ca. 11000 digits written by 44 persons. What if the data is clustered according to the person who wrote? (I.e. is it easier to recognize an 8 written by someone if you know how that person writes, say, a 3?) The effective sample size then may be as low as 44.
- Tuning model hyperparameters may lead to correlation between the models (in fact, that would be considered well behaved from a numerical optimization perspective). It is difficult to predict the influence of that (and I suspect this is impossible without taking into account the actual type of classifier).

In general, however, both low number of independent test cases and high number of compared models increase the bias. Also, the Cawley and Talbot paper gives empirical observed behaviour.

Comment: @cbleites: If grid search might not be an appropriate method for finding the optimal model, what method should I choose then?

Comment: @ta.ft: two approaches are a) incorporate as much external knowledge about your application and data into the modeling in order to drastically reduce the number of models that need to be compared (= decide hyperparameters instead of optimizing). It may be overall better to change to a classifier that has intrinsically meaningful hyperparameters, i.e. where you can know from application and data type what the hyperparameter should (approximately) be. b) compare the few remaining models by proper scoring rule. E.g. Briers score has far better variance properties for many classifiers.

Comment: You can also refuse to optimize at all (via decisions (a)). If you get a good-enough classifier and can argue that you have no chance to prove superiority of another classifier given the available sample size (e.g. do some demo McNemar calculations, look up necessary sample size for proportion comparisons for a hypothetic better classifier - there's a good chance that these will be ridiculously large even for ridiculously large hypothetical improvements), you can argue that optimization does not make any sense and just creates a risk of overfitting.

Comment: I don't agree with you on "skimming variance". If you have lots of points in the grid for hyperparameter optimization, a point may opportunistically get lucky in one fold of the CV; but if you have, let's say 10-fold CV, it is still unlikely a set of parameter will accidentally get lucky on all 10 folds of the CV.

Comment: @RNA: The probability to be "lucky" in all folds is directly connected to the total number of cases (in all 10 folds), and typically only the average over all those folds is considered. I updated the answer with a simulation of a hypothetical picking of the best of 100 models (say, 2 hyperparameters with 10 steps each), which is already associated with a considerable bias for the example scenario (error rate too low by 1/3). Many people here rarely have a few thousand independent cases at hand - e.g. I rarely have even the 44 individuals who wrote digits for the full UCI digits data set.